# SonarQube Fsharp Plugin

Tags: f#, sonarqube

Latest Update: 
Issue fixed https://github.com/jmecsoftware/sonar-fsharp-plugin/releases/tag/1.0.2

Note that this is the original repository but the one given in SonarQube plugin library page is a fork which is outdated.

---

Updated SonarQube to 6.7.1 LTS. The issue persists.
Now I can see there are `sonar.log`, `es.log`, `web.log`... etc..

Here is what I get from `sonar.log`:

```
2018.02.14 17:33:36 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{dVmenN90RZqwE7eb-lsQ8Q}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}], ignoring...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9001] connect_timeout[30s]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.connectToChannels(Netty4Transport.java:362)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:570)
```

And from `web.log`

```
2018.02.14 17:26:50 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube

java.lang.IllegalStateException: RuleDefinition not found for key fsharplint:RulesXmlDocumentationAutoPropertyError

at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.BuiltInQProfileInsertImpl.lambda$insertActiveRule$4(BuiltInQProfileInsertImpl.java:145)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)

at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.BuiltInQProfileInsertImpl.insertActiveRule(BuiltInQProfileInsertImpl.java:145)

at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.BuiltInQProfileInsertImpl.lambda$create$0(BuiltInQProfileInsertImpl.java:86)
```

It looks like it is the cause of the issue:

`RuleDefinition not found for key fsharplint:RulesXmlDocumentationAutoPropertyError` but I do not know what it means or how to resolve it. Please can anyone help?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I am trying to install fsharp plugin (https://github.com/jmecosta/sonar-fsharp-plugin) in my SonarQube (5.6.6 LTS). I am able to build to fsharp plugin using appveyor (cloud). I got two jar files (sonarqube-fsharp-plugin-1.0.1.jar and sonarqube-fsharp-plugin-1.0.1-sources.jar) and I copied them to the sonarqube plugin folder (sonarqube\extensions\plugins). When I run sonarqube, it couldn't start. It says:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.server.exceptions.BadRequestException: Rule not found: 
fsharplint:RulesXmlDocumentationExceptionError
```

Here is the log:

```
2018.02.12 16:06:33 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.server.exceptions.BadRequestException: Rule not found: fsharplint:RulesXmlDocumentationExceptionError
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RuleActivatorContextFactory.initRule(RuleActivatorContextFactory.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RuleActivatorContextFactory.create(RuleActivatorContextFactory.java:69) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RuleActivatorContextFactory.create(RuleActivatorContextFactory.java:61) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RuleActivator.activate(RuleActivator.java:85) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RegisterQualityProfiles.register(RegisterQualityProfiles.java:157) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RegisterQualityProfiles.registerProfilesForLanguage(RegisterQualityProfiles.java:131) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RegisterQualityProfiles.start(RegisterQualityProfiles.java:98) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320) ~[sonar-core-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141) ~[sonar-core-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.access$001(PlatformLevelStartup.java:45) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:80) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:201) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:114) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
2018.02.12 16:06:33 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2018.02.12 16:06:33 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2018.02.12 16:06:33 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.02.12 16:06:34 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2018.02.12 16:06:34 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2018.02.12 16:06:34 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:47) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
2018.02.12 16:06:34 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.02.12 16:06:35 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.02.12 16:06:35 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.02.12 16:06:35 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2018.02.12 16:06:36 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2018.02.12 16:06:36 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1518422777357] stopping ...
2018.02.12 16:06:36 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1518422777357] stopped
2018.02.12 16:06:36 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1518422777357] closing ...
2018.02.12 16:06:36 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1518422777357] closed
2018.02.12 16:06:36 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
Wrapper Process has not received any CPU time for 72 seconds.  Extending timeouts.
2018.02.12 16:06:36 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Does anyone have any idea on this? 
Are there any alternatives?

Comment: In `$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs` there are multiple log files. You appear to have excerpted `sonar.log`. You should also check 'web.log`, `es.log`, and `ce.log`. One of them should have a more meaningful error message. If you still have questions after finding it, please [edit] your question to include the specific error.

Comment: I only have two logs in the folder "access.log" and "server.log". I have turned on the log level to TRACE just now, and can still only see the error being: `Rule not found: fsharplint:RulesXmlDocumentationExceptionError`

Comment: I have upgraded to the latest LTS version 6.7.1 and can see multiple logs now.